# Change navigation on window-scroll with a line under Menu-Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that makes active menu item with moving line, but this is one-page and I want that during scroll active menu change. I tried diffrent scripts [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/) but it doesn't work.

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="menu">
       <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#skup">Skup</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tel_zast">Sprzedaż</a></li>
       <li><a href="#akces">Serwis</a></li>
       <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
       <div id="line"></div>
   </ul>
```

JS(on fiddle because stack wants more details) :
https://jsfiddle.net/6y6qj02y/

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the Scrollspy.
This is how you can do it: